# Task throttling not working with ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, throttling

I am trying to throttle the number of async tasks that I submit to an external database server.  I created the following test code which should take 25 seconds to execute (150 tasks * 5 seconds / 30 max concurrent tasks = 25 seconds).

```
    private async void ThrottlingTest()
    {
        TaskScheduler scheduler = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair(TaskScheduler.Default, 30).ConcurrentScheduler;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        int numTasks = 150;
        Task[] tasks = new Task[numTasks];

        for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Task.Delay(5000), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler).Unwrap();
        }

        sw.Start();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        sw.Stop();
        long duration = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
```

However, this code only takes 5 seconds to execute indicating my throttling is not working.  What am I doing wrong?  I suspect Task.Delay is running using the default scheduler.  If so, what delay mechanism can I test with?

Comment: By using ConcurrentScheduler 30 you said to the os, only use 30 thread for this application. Task.Delay wont consume thread (contrary to thread.sleep, in async code, delay dont BLOCK the thread this point is very important), So as you do almost no job, 150 tasks are openned, on max 30 thread. Tasks will be delayed on these thread and as no jobs are request but a delay, the result will be print in 5000 ms.

Comment: To check your code, you can use this example, https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Your answer explains this behavior.  However, before I posted, I tried several examples, including the one you linked using "TaskScheduler scheduler = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(30);"  The behavior is identical, 5 seconds instead of 25 seconds for the entire run.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to throttle the number of async tasks that I submit to an external database server.

`TaskScheduler`s can only be used to control the number of *running* tasks. Asynchronous tasks do not "run". They can be "in progress", but they are not actually *running code* while being so. Put another way, `TaskScheduler`s only work as expected with synchronous tasks. Or if you want to use [this terminology](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html), `TaskScheduler`s were designed for Delegate Tasks; they do not understand Promise Tasks.

To throttle asynchronous operations, use `SemaphoreSlim` instead:

```
private async void ThrottlingTest()
{
  SemaphoreSlim mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(30);
  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

  int numTasks = 150;
  Task[] tasks = new Task[numTasks];
  for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++)
    tasks[i] = TestAsync();

  sw.Start();
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  sw.Stop();
  long duration = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

  async Task TestAsync()
  {
    await mutex.WaitAsync();
    try { await Task.Delay(5000); }
    finally { mutex.Release(); }
  }
}
```